# Detecting the differences between two string vectors

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr

I've got a `data_frame` that looks like this.

```
df <- data_frame(name = c('john','bill','amy'),
           name.2 = c('johhn','ball','ammy')) 
df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   name name.2
  <chr>  <chr>
1  john  johhn
2  bill   ball
3   amy   ammy
```

I want to add a column that shows the difference between the two name(.2) columns. Like this:

```
df %>% 
mutate(diff = c('h','a','m')) 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   name name.2  diff
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1  john  johhn     h
2  bill   ball     a
3   amy   ammy     m
```

I'd prefer to find a solution that uses elements of `tidyverse` and `stringr` if possible, but I'll take it like I get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using base R we canndo something like:

```
diffc=diag(attr(adist(df$name,df$name.2, counts = TRUE), "trafos"))
transform(df,diff=regmatches(name.2,regexpr("[^M]",diffc)))
  name name.2 diff
1 john  johhn    h
2 bill   ball    a
3  amy   ammy    m
```

Breakdown:

compute approximate string distance between `df[,1]` and `df[,2]`

```
  d=adist(df$name,df$name.2, counts = TRUE)
```

obtain the diagonal of the transformation matrix:

```
   e= diag(attr(d, "trafos"))
```

Find the position of those that are either deleted,substituted or inserted ie not maintained:

```
    f=regexpr("[^M]",e)
```

extract the values of `df[,2]` at those specified positions:

```
     dat$diff==regmatches(name.2,f)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Do you mind explaining a bit what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: I don't mind. first it Computes the approximate string distance between the character vectors. by the use of `adist()`. It then picks the transformation matrix ie `trafos`.this is by the use of the function `attr` since `trafos` is an attribute within the output. Then takes the diagonal of that and matches it back to the original vector. Look at `?adist`. That might help

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `vecsets` library:

```
library(vecsets)
df$diff <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(df$name.2, split = ""),
                            strsplit(df$name, split = ""))

df
#  name name.2 diff
#1 john  johhn    h
#2 bill   ball    a
#3  amy   ammy    m
```

Note it looks like you just want the values in `name.2` that are not in `name` which is why the first argument to `mapply` is the `strsplit` of `name.2`.